Transfer data to the same row at different times
I have created a userform to submit data to the respective cellssatrting from column G.But it was not working as intended. I want to match a date in textbox1 from the userform to column G, if the date is not found, add a new row and populate the the columns based on value from the textboxes.
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim targetsheet As String
    targetsheet = ComboBox1.Value
    
    ' Check if targetsheet is empty, exit the sub if true
    If targetsheet = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets(targetsheet)
    Dim Lookup As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim SalesClm As Integer
    Dim IvfClm As Integer
    Dim MomoClm As Integer

    ' Disable error handling temporarily
    On Error Resume Next
    Lookup = Me.TextBox1.Value
    
    ' Use Match function to find the lookup value in column G
    lastRow = Application.Match(Lookup, ws.Range("G5:G"), 0)
    
    SalesClm = 2
    IvfClm = 3
    MomoClm = 4
    ' Check if the lookup value was found
    If Not IsError(lastRow) Then
        ' Insert a new row below the last used row in column G
        ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

        ' Populate data into respective columns based on TextBox values
        If Me.TextBox2 <> "" Then ws.Cells(lastRow, SalesClm) = Me.TextBox2.Value
        If Me.TextBox3 <> "" Then ws.Cells(lastRow, IvfClm) = Me.TextBox3.Value
        If Me.TextBox4 <> "" Then ws.Cells(lastRow, MomoClm) = Me.TextBox4.Value

        If Me.TextBox5 <> "" Then ws.Cells(lastRow, SalesClm + 3) = Me.TextBox5.Value
        If Me.TextBox6 <> "" Then ws.Cells(lastRow, IvfClm + 3) = Me.TextBox6.Value
        If Me.TextBox7 <> "" Then ws.Cells(lastRow, MomoClm + 3) = Me.TextBox7.Value

        If Me.TextBox8 <> "" Then ws.Cells(lastRow, SalesClm + 6) = Me.TextBox8.Value
        If Me.TextBox9 <> "" Then ws.Cells(lastRow, IvfClm + 6) = Me.TextBox9.Value
        If Me.TextBox10 <> "" Then ws.Cells(lastRow, MomoClm + 6) = Me.TextBox10.Value
        
        MsgBox "Data was added successfully"
        
        ' Clear TextBox values after data insertion
        With Me
            .TextBox2.Value = ""
            .TextBox3.Value = ""
            .TextBox4.Value = ""
            .TextBox5.Value = ""
            .TextBox6.Value = ""
            .TextBox7.Value = ""
            .TextBox8.Value = ""
            .TextBox9.Value = ""
            .TextBox10.Value = ""
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    ComboBox1.Clear
    
    ' Fill ComboBox1 with worksheet names from the workbook
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ComboBox1.AddItem sh.Name
    Next sh
End Sub


imagelink:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NJcVD4w6JVLFa0z6RiuynCS3bh1C61Yp/view?usp=drive_link

I am using a userform to transfer the data

"Please assist me" with what specifically?   What is the problem you're having exactly?  You've not really told us what should happen instead of data going to the next row.

I want to  use a userform to submit data to the income column morning, afternoon and evening, but to submit it at different times to the same row.

OK - what is the specific problem you're having with doing that?  Have you created a userform?

Yes, This is the link to the user form, when you submit it goes to the next row not the same row. For example is you submit for same 01/04/2024, morning, afternoon and evening should be on the same row. Thank you                                                                      https://drive.google.com/file/d/17KK4liGzj-rfwwLBezpWd-FYe2dGY6HI/view?usp=sharing

Put a Watch on 'lastrow ' and see what its value is...  With this information, you should be able to debug the issue.

What you need to do: (1) Match the date from your userform to a date in Col G - if not found then add a new row.  (2)Match the "time" from your userform to a header on row 3   Using (1) and (2) you can now populate the correct cell with the amount from the userform.

Okay thanks for the gist, I will try

@Tim Williams, I have tried and modified the userform and the code but still not working. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NJcVD4w6JVLFa0z6RiuynCS3bh1C61Yp/view?usp=sharing       and code link-https://drive.google.com/file/d/11D_B9Fft6knGZF1_4qapphkK1TwVjOZA/view?usp=drive_link

You can edit your post and update the code there.  Please also clarify exactly what you mean by "not working'?  You have On Error Resume Next at the top of your code but you don't cancel it.
